# How to calculate divided irrigation discharge from a Parshall flume

Tags: fluid-dynamics

How do I calculate the discharge from a Parshall flume that flow over a bulkhead into three partitions divided 25%/50%/25%?  The 25% partitions feed 8" pipe, while the 50% partition feeds a 10" pipe.  When either of the 25% partitions are closed, a downstream gate can be opened to dump that partition into the 10" pipe.

If either of the 25% partitions are closed, and the downstream gate on the closed partition is closed, does the discharge flow change to 33%/66%?

If either of the 25% partitions are closed and the downstream gate on the closed partition is open, does the discharge flow change to 25%/75%?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Engineering question.

Comment: Thank you, I'll move this question over to that forum...